# Can't change document root for apache 2.4

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, homebrew

I want to set up local web server using Apache and PHP on my Mac running Sierra. I followed this tutorial:

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

And I am stuck at changing the document root from httpd.config, for whatever reason this change does not take effect at all. If I type http://localhost it still says "It works", it still uses the original html file.

Another weird thing is that apparently I can't stop apache at all. I tried running

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

but I still can’t access http://localhost

if I run

```
$ brew services list
```

httpd24 is stopped. What gives? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an instance of apache pre-installed with macOS. So you have now two versions of apache installed. If you check:

```
which  apachectl
```

you will probably obtain:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

which is the official macOS version of `apachectl`. Stop it with:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Disable the auto-loading of the pre-installed apache with (as explained in [the tutorial you mentioned](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions)):

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

To run the homebrew version do:

```
brew services run httpd24
```

to stop it:

```
brew services stop httpd24
```

to register it to launch at login:

```
brew services start httpd24
```